# How can I get how frequent is a number in in a specific range

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have dataframe that contains 2 columns ('timestamp', 'ip') and 400 rows

```
timestamp     ip

1000          ip1

1500          ip2
 .             .
 .             .

11000         ip1
 .             . 
 .             .

50000         ip5
```

what I want to do is to check if the difference between every 10th row and 1 row of every 10 rows  in column 1 is <= 10  if yes get the value that get repeated the most in column 2 in and delete it from the dataframe only  in this rows where the test is true

So what I want t o get is  to create a loop with step 10 and go through the first column and make the test between the 10th and 1 row if the result is true I do another loop to get the get the 10 rows in a list and then get the ip that repeats the most in this list and try to deleted from the original dataframe but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach this how my code looks like :

```
#created an empty list
list=[]
#create a dataframe from the csv file
read=pd.read_csv(r"example.csv", delimiter = ';')
#get the number of rws in the csv file
lines = sum(1 for line in open('example.csv'))
#my first loop to make the test on the  10000 with the step 10 
for i in range(0, lines-1, 10):
    if  int((read['timestamp'][i+1]))-(int (read['timestamp'][i]) )<= 10000:
# second loop the extract the result in a list
        for j  in range (i,i+10) :
           l.append(read['ip'][j])
           df = pd.DataFrame({'ip':l})
        print(df)
        l=[]
```

so the result that I get from this code is like this :

```py
                           IP
0                          ip1
1                          ip2
2                          ip3
3                          ip4
4                          ip5
5                          ip5
6                          ip5
7                          ip1
8                          ip5
9                          ip6

All what i want to do now is to get which ip is the most frequent and how frequent is this ip that means
Ip5 :4
```

Comment: First of all please reread your question and ask yourself, if it is understandable. Do you mean to compare the 10th with the first or the 10th with the 11th row? Your question says the first, your code the second... Secondly, what does your code return? Is it working? What is the expected result, what is the actual result? What exactly is your question? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yeah my bad I forgot to doubel check. The result that I get is a list but with more than 10 values

Comment: Still your code contradicts your words. Do you want to compare to the first row or the i+1th row?

Comment: And can you please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: for i in range(0, lines-1, 10)
    if  int((read['timestamp'][i+1]))-(int (read['timestamp'][i]) )<= 10000:   because I'm having a step of 10 so it merans I'm comparing the  first and the 10 th row!!

Comment: No you don't! Lets go through this, in your first iteration `i = 0` and `i+1 = 1` so you subtract the time of the second row from the first. Then in the next iteration `i = 10` and `i+1 = 11` so, you subtract the eleventh row from the tenth row. `i+1` is **not** a move to the next range list element but just a simple integer add of`+1`! And even if it would you would only compare it to the first row in the first iteration! Afterwrds `i = 10` **not** `i=0`! Try this for proof: `for i in range (0, 1000, 10):
 print(i, i+1)`

Comment: yeah you have right I missed a 0 so it should be like this :                                            for i in range(0, lines-1, 10) if int((read['timestamp'][i+10]))-(int (read['timestamp'][i]) )<= 10000

Comment: But this still does not compare all rows to the first, but rather the 11th to the first and the 21st to the 11th and so on. It still contradicts your words.

Comment: yeah that is what i also want to do !!!!

Comment: Okay, then can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproductive Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I need an example df to test with, otherwise I can't try things out that might work. Also what do you want the code to do if two IPs appear the same number of times? e.g. ip1 5 times and ip2 5 times? remove both? remove neither?

Comment: And thank you, after the last edit it is correct, sorry if that annoyed you, it just easily leads to confusion. Just make sure, that the question really represents, what you are asking for and matches the code you provide ;)

Answer (score 1):

So this is the fastest way I could think of to achieve what you want. However you still have to handle the case of two ips occurring the same number of times. Right now it chooses the smaller one in this case.

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame()
while len(read) > 10:
    sub_df, read = read.iloc[:10], read.iloc[10:] if len(read) > 10 else (read, pd.DataFrame())
    if sub_df.tail(1)['Time'].values[0] - sub_df.head(1)['Time'].values[0] <= 10000 and len(sub_df) == 10:
        sub_df = sub_df[sub_df["IP"] != sub_df['IP'].value_counts().index.values[0]]
    out_df = pd.concat([out_df, sub_df])
```

The code creates sub-dataframes to manipulate and then pushes them back into a large dataframe. The method `value_counts()` is even so nice to sort the elements by their occurrence, so we can simply take the first one of them. I tested it with some randomly generated values and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it is the solution to your problem, so that everybody knows, that it works, if anybody ever has the same problem :) And your welcome :)